# I am creating a token whenever I test using truffle , it gives undeclared identifier error and in console

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Xotik {

    string public name = "Xotik";

    string public symbol = "XOT";
    string public standard = "Xotik v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function Xotik(uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        // totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    //Transfer
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of truffle console is here]

Answer (score 0):

Your Transfer event is not defined, you should add : `event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);` in your state variables declaration